# C# Adding Short Date Type

Tags: c#

dtUcusTarihi is a dateTimePicker and I want to return the value ONLY date which is dd/mm/yyyy without time, but when I try value returns like 20.01.2019 00:00:0000 so I can not INSERT into my msAccess (Short Date type)

How can I figure it out? Please help.

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ucusTarih", Convert.ToDateTime(dtUcusTarihi.Value.Date));
```

also I got another one. In this section I want ONLY ShortTime with dateTimePicker which is HH:mm to add my msAccess (Short Time type)

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ucusSaat", Convert.ToDateTime(dtUcusSaati.Value.TimeOfDay));
```

Comment: `but when i try value returns like 20.01.2019 00:00:0000 so i can not INSERT to my msAccess (Short Date type)` `DateTime` **always** contains a time component (even a date that seems to lack a time component actually has one - it has midnight as shown in your example). This shouldn't impact your ability to insert it. What makes you think this is your issue? Your first code sample should work just fine.

Comment: Don't use `AddWithValue`, use `Add`, specifying the `Date` type, and then set the Value` of the newly added parameter (to a `DateTime`)

Answer (score 0):

Ok i handle it

```
command.Parameters.Add("@ucusTarih",OleDbType.Date).Value=dtUcusSaati.Value;

command.Parameters.Add("@ucusSaat", Convert.ToDateTime(dtUcusSaati.Value).ToShortTimeString());
```

Thanks @Flydog57

Comment: `.ToShortTimeString()` is a terrible idea. It means you are passing it as a string. As per https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/320435/info-oledbtype-enumeration-vs-microsoft-access-data-types you should be using `OleDbType.Date`.